# GNU "parallel --pipe" doesn't process stdin by lines

Tags: pipe, gnu-parallel

I'm super confused about how to use GNU parallel to pass stdin to the job command.

I have what I imagined to be a *really* common use case. I have some process `xxd` that does something with stdin and outputs to stdout. I have some way to generate or get work from another standard stream, for example`seq 3`, and I can combine the two and make an impromptu power tool like so:

```
$ seq 3 | while read line; do echo $line | xxd; done
00000000: 310a                                     1.
00000000: 320a                                     2.
00000000: 330a                                     3.
```

Great. We can clearly see that each invocation of `xxd` gets one line, and a trailing newline is appended.

This is what piping to `parallel` does:

```
$ seq 3 | parallel --pipe --recend="\n" -L 1 xxd
...

00000000: 310a 320a 330a                           1.2.3.
```

`parallel --pipe` takes all of stdin and sends it to one invocation of `xxd` which confuses me because all the documented parameters and their defaults seem to contradict this behavior: `--recend="\n"` (the default) delimits jobs by newline, `-L 1` (the default) sends a maximum of one line to the command.

Null separators have the same problem. They're also passed though verbatim:

```
seq 3 | tr '\n' '\0' | parallel --null --pipe xxd
...

00000000: 3100 3200 3300                           1.2.3.
```

---

An explanation for this behavior would be appreciated, especially since these parameters appear to apply specifically to the `--pipe` mode of `parallel`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are SO close. `-L` sets the record *size* (in lines) but not how many records should be sent. This is controlled by `-N`. Default `--recend` is `\n` so that is not needed. Default `-L` is 1, so that is not needed.

```
seq 3 | parallel --pipe -N 1 xxd
```

Answer (score 1):

- `--pipe` sends stdin to job, implies `--recend '\n'`
- `-N1` send one captured input to one job

```
seq 3 | parallel --pipe -N1 xxd
```

---

Old Answer:

<strike>**Warning:** this may corrupt your data stream as `echo` is interpreting the payload. It may work for ascii and utf-8 encoded strings, but I wouldn't trust it generally!</strike>

Instead of pipe mode, echo (or similar) can convert args back to stout per-job

```
$ seq 3 | parallel "echo {} | xxd"
00000000: 310a                                     1.
00000000: 320a                                     2.
00000000: 330a                                     3.
```

Comment: Good job. Upvoted for sharing knowledge this way.